# if, elif and else.. priority and chains

Tags: python, if-statement

I always had this curiosity about Python and I can't find a clear answer, maybe someone can help me
what is the "if", "elif" and "else"  priority and way of working?
if I do:

```
if conditionA:
    do something
elif conditionB:
    do something else
else:
    do something else
```

does the "else" check  the condition in "elif" or both conditions "if" and "elif"?
is there any interesting order in which they can be used (e.g. if, else, elif, else etc.) ?
thanks

Comment: It's very well explained here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html. There must be exactly one `if`, then zero or more `elif`, then zero or one `else` statements.

Comment: If you just speak the logic out loud, it should very much be obvious what the *priority* is.  *if condition A is true, then do action A.  else if condition B is true, then do action B.  else do action C*

Comment: If you have to ask, the next guy reading your code will have to ask as well (and the next guy is likely to be you!).  I suggest not using anything that would be used so rarely as to not be instantly understood, instead use more verbose code to make it more clear (May involve code sections or breaking parts off into well-named methods).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`else` is the catch-all after all the `if` and `elif` statements were false. Putting it in the middle would be a syntax error.

Don't think of the `else` "checking the conditions." Think of it as the control flow never even reaches the `else` if the others were true. The same is true for multiple `elif`.

Consider this:

```
if False:
    print 'first'
elif True:
    print 'second'
elif True:
    print 'third'
```

Even `third` won't print, because the second one was true. It doesn't matter that the third was true, because it's not even evaluated.

This can have some side effects too, if you're calling functions:

```
if send_email(to_coworker):
    pass
elif send_email(to_boss):
    pass
```

Assuming the function returns `True` if it succeeds, the email to your boss will only send if the email to your coworker fails, *even though the function would need to be called to evaluate the elif condition*

Answer (score 1):

They're processed in the order that they're encountered in the file.

```
if True:
  # Always executes.
elif False:
  # Is never checked.
else:
  # We never get this far, either.
```

As soon as the first condition that evaluates True is encountered the corresponding block of code is executed.  Additional conditions aren't checked.

Answer (score 1):

They don't have priorities for itself, what really matters is the order, so the first condition will be checked and if the first condition is False than the second condition is checked and so on until any condition is True or it executes the else statement if and only if all conditions where False

In your example if conditionA is True then the code inside the if statement will be executed and the elif and else conditions will not matter at all.

If conditionA is False and conditionB is True than the code inside the elif statement will be executed.

Finally only when the conditionA and conditionB is False then the code inside else block will be executed