# Whenever I write elif or else in my code I get a Syntax Error. Why is this?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am trying to write code for a simple Rock Paper Scissors and I got stuck here because else or elif don't work in my code. [This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuL79.png)

I tried looking up why this didn't work and I couldn't find anything on the subject.

Comment: Indentation is important in Python, this is one of the first things you should have learned. `elif` and `else` have to be at the same indentation as `if`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: `if`, `else`, etc should all be at the same indent level. The code inside of each block should be the only thing indented.

Comment: Why are you indenting the `else` statement?  No tutorial in the world would have said to do it this way.  Where did you learn to do it that way?

Comment: I am just following what my teacher has told me. He said it was just basic coding for Python for  8th grade

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems you are mixing the order how to use `if`-`elif`-`else`.

The following is quoted from
[if, elif and else.. priority and chains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546826/if-elif-and-else-priority-and-chains) (I recommend reading it fully):

> `else` is the catch-all after all the `if` and `elif` statements were `False`. Putting it in the middle would be a syntax error.

To demonstrate how the `if`-`elif`-`else` blocks work:

```py
if False:
    print 'first'
elif True:
    print 'second'
elif True:
    print 'third' "
```

Comment: Thank you! I just started using Python in my coding class so i'm kinda dumb to this stuff.